# Guidance Automation Extension Installation - blank popup

Tags: guidance-automation-tool

i got this weird popup while installing GAE. Any ideas ?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f2fa08b9c7.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f2fa08b9c7.jpg)

Comment: Looks pretty weird to me - I can't even _see_ it!

Comment: It might help if you mentioned what the popup said.

Comment: @John Saunders - nice sense of humor, he he. It's added now.

Comment: @Mike - yeah that's the problem, it doesn't say anything! Image uploaded, it's hosted  on freeimagehosting, so please be patient while it's loading.

Comment: That didn't help. Not your fault. Clearly it just wants to tell you that everything is okay. Don't Panic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guidance Automation without proper guidance, that is. I just uninstalled it. This is clearly a buggy software from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, do you have an existing GAE installed? or GAT?

you can run the installer with msiexec -i  /vi*x packageinstall.log to get a lot more information. I did all kinds of crazy registry edits and and other articles found on the web.

My question to MS is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsgatk/thread/5029c831-92cf-4f86-b2d3-bb796054e7de)

Finally after running the force uninstaller (as mine said it was installed but not functional) I finally got it going.